# Revoke access_token in .net Web API 2 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am developing an API for an iOS app. We have an usecase where user is able to log out the list of devices he previous logged in to. Just like Facebook lets its user log out of the all the devices.

I searched everywhere but all in vain - can you guys help me with this situation?

Comment: Just add the accesstoken into a table of invalid accesstokens and check on auth if the table doesnt contain that accesstoken.

Comment: But then again, this will only work during login. What if i want to revoke a token for a user who is already logged into the system? What you’re suggesting, if I am not wrong. That we then have to put a check on every function ours.

Comment: Dont you check the token in your api on every request? Something like the AuthorizationAttribute? This does what you want: check if the token exists and whether it‘s valid. Or do you have your token only for login and you dont validate it on any requests?

Comment: What i want to be able to do, have a generated token be revoked. Now, the problem is There is no way to revoke a token, since the login flow for the app is login->get accesstoken -> store token in local storage. Now the problem is. Once the token is generated and stored in local storage, i have no method to revoke that token which has been generated. Get me?

Comment: Yes thats what i wrote in the first comment. Your api should check that token on every request. When the token is in that table, your api rejects the token and returns an unauthorized status and the client needs to login. The api should say if the token is okay or not. Not the client or local storage or sth. When your client gets a „unauthorized“ you need the user to login.

Comment: Or you should use shorter lived tokens and then use a refresh token to get a new token transparently.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to i modify  AuthorizationAttribute so it throws 401 error for tokens stored in invalid token table?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger it worked man!! Thank you very much ..

Comment: I know :p implemented it myself in my project. I‘m glad I could help.